# What is causing this "MySQL error #1054 - Unknown column" error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I'm having a little problem with this MySQL query. I've already used an suggestion I've seen in another question but still doesn't work....

Here's the code

```
$kernel->db->query( "UPDATE `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "users` 
                        SET `total_downs` = `total_downs` + 1 
                      WHERE `phcdl_files`.`file_author` = " . $file['file_author'] );
```

Which gives

> Invalid SQL Query
>   Unknown column 'phcdl_files.file_author' in 'where clause' (MySQL error no; 1054)

Comment: Where is table `phcdl_files` in your query??

Comment: You have a sql injection vulnerability. Please use prepared queries. See PDO in the php docs.

Comment: `phcdl_files` isn't a table in your query.

Comment: Is there a relationship between `users` and `file_author`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means that the column file_author doesn't exist in the table phcdl_files. You probably want

```
$kernel->db->query( "UPDATE " . TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET total_downs = total_downs + 1 WHERE file_author = " . $file['file_author'] );
```

EDIT: please see the comment by Byron Whitlock above. You generally don't want to insert a variable directly into a SQL query string.

Comment: You'll need to add "users" to the end of TABLE_PREFIX in the WHERE clause, according to the first part of that query. Or, since it's a column in the only table referenced in the query, just leave the table name out...

Comment: @djacobson: Thanks, just caught that myself.

Comment: @ithcy - Your first version contained a reference to `phcdl_files` which isn't a table defined anywhere in the query. Seems to have been removed now even though your explanatory text still talks about it!

Comment: @Martin: I understand. I thought you meant "the query doesn't reference a table at all" :)

Comment: ouch, my mistake, so much headaches because i was using the user name of files table (the author) instead the actual user name in users table

Answer (score 1):

If `phcdl_files` is the name of a table, you need to *include* that table in your query, and express some relationship between it and the rows in `TABLE_PREFIXusers` that you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

where is  `phcdl_files`.`file_author`?

```
 "UPDATE `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "users` 
          SET `total_downs` = `total_downs` + 1 
          WHERE `user`.`file_author` = " . $file['file_author']
```

and $file['file_author'] should come from phcdl_files table